# Fullcalendar: accept dragged elements from external sources

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar, draggable

I want to drag html elements from a different application onto my FullCalendar app. The other application does not have access to the FullCalendar library, so it cannot use `Fullcalendar.Draggable`.

I tried adapting the demo found at `https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging-demo`, to remove the call to `Draggable` in line 12 and set `draggable='true'` on the `div.fc-event` elements in the html. However, this does not work. I can drag the `fc-event` elements onto the calendar, but they cannot be dropped.

Is there another way I can convince FullCalendar to accept dragging of arbitrary html elements?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, unless you write your own plugin for fullcalendar to try and achieve it.